# Gaussian Addition - Python Challenge

Tags: python

I am currently working on some beginner python challenges, I just finished a gaussian addition challenge. I was able to get the output that the challenge was looking for, but it seems like I over complicated things.

**The challenge is as follows:**

Write a program that passes a list of numbers to a function.

- The function should use a while loop to keep popping the first and last numbers from the list and calculate the sum of those two numbers.
- The function should print out the current numbers that are being added, and print their partial sum.
- The function should keep track of how many partial sums there are.
- The function should then print out how many partial sums there were.
- The function should perform Gauss' multiplication, and report the final answer.
- Prove that your function works, by passing in the range 1-100, and verifying that you get 5050.
  *gauss_addition(list(range(1,101)))*
- Your function should work for any set of consecutive numbers, as long as that set has an even length.
- **Bonus**: Modify your function so that it works for any set of consecutive numbers, whether that set has an even or odd length.

**My function is as follows:**

```
def gauss(numbers):
    for number in numbers:
        while len(numbers) > 0:
            num1 = numbers.pop(0)
            print(num1)
            num2 = numbers.pop(-1)
            print(num2)
            calc = num1 + num2
            print(str(num1) + " + " + str(num2) + " = " + str(calc))
    print("Final answer is: " + str(num1 * calc))
    
           
gauss(list(range(1,101)))
```

Can someone explain how I can simplify this function without the use of python modules? I understand how the function that I wrote is working, but I also want to know if there is an easier, "more condensed" way of achieving this.

I should specify that I only know the basics of python...

Comment: If your code works and seek improvement ideas - suggest to go here https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Is it possible to transfer my question to that site without opening a new question on code-review?

Comment: This problem seems to be related to *interleaving* a list (then sum) and if so, you don't have to repeatedly do `pop` - that's costly.

Comment: Interesting... Although, the challenge is mostly focused on using the while loop.

Comment: The *pop* is O(1) to pop the last element of a Python list, and O(N) to pop an arbitrary element (since the whole rest of the list has to be shifted).

Comment: @DanielHao do you care to explain further in a chat? I'm not sure if I fully understand what you mean by this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using list to approach this problem seems to be too expensive, for the reason of repeatedly *pop* will be costly as cited in early notes.

So instead of it, you can consider using collections module *deque* which will allow you to do the operations (pop) in both end efficiently.

**Note** - it will work well if the list is even-sized, but that's part of requirements already.

So the solution will be like this:

```
#
from collections import deque

dq = deque(range(1, 101))  # create a list (dq list)

total = 0
count = 0

while dq:
    x, y = dq.popleft(), dq.pop()
    print(x, y, x+y, end='\t')
    count +=  1       # how many partial sum?
    print(count)
    total += (x+y)


print(f' final total: {total} ')
```

Outputs:  *(partial - it's too long)*

```
1 100 101   1
2 99 101    2
3 98 101    3
4 97 101    4
5 96 101    5
...........
...........
48 53 101   48
49 52 101   49
50 51 101   50
final total: 5050
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do the following

```
def gauss(numbers):
    if len(numbers)% 2 != 0 :
        numbers.append(0)
    for number in numbers:
        while len(numbers) > 0:
            num1 = numbers.pop(0)
            print(num1)
            num2 = numbers.pop(-1)
            print(num2)
            calc = num1 + num2
            print(str(num1) + " + " + str(num2) + " = " + str(calc))
    print("Final answer is: " + str(num1 * calc))
         
gauss(list(range(1,8)))
```

Comment: It looks like you're posting an answer, please explain what it is doing (add comments and a description of the logic), eventually compare it to the existing answer. Finally, remove the "Is it right??" and "I hope it will help" which are not bringing anything useful.